# VBA- Hide rows based on whether cell contains specific text

Tags: vba, excel, multiple-columns, cells

Looking to scan through a whole column to see if the product (in individual cell) may be discontinued. This is true if the word discontinued is in a cell. I want the whole row to be hidden if it is discontinued. Any suggestions?

```
Sub HideRows()
    Dim c As Range
    For Each c In Range("B3:B2452")
        If InStr(1, c, "Discontinued") Or InStr(1, c, "discontinued") Then
            c.EntireRow.Hidden = True
        End If
        Next
End Sub
```

Comment: What is the behavior it is giving you right now?

Comment: Was manually typed, updated as a copied version now.

Comment: Right now, this doesn't do anything...

Comment: I just tried this, and it is working for me.

Comment: In the future, cases like this are normally figured out using the debugger pretty easily.

Comment: @RonanGarrison Why don't you use a filter ??? Will be much faster

Comment: @SandPiper what is the debugger?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Sub HideRows()

    Dim rCheck As Range
    Dim rHide As Range
    Dim rCheckCell As Range

    Set rCheck = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("B3:B2452")
    rCheck.EntireRow.Hidden = False

    For Each rCheckCell In rCheck.Cells
        If InStr(1, rCheckCell, "Discontinued", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
            If Not rHide Is Nothing Then Set rHide = Union(rHide, rCheckCell) Else Set rHide = rCheckCell
        End If
    Next rCheckCell

    If Not rHide Is Nothing Then rHide.EntireRow.Hidden = True

End Sub
```